# XCode IDE Method/Class Definition Drop Down

Tags: xcode, ide

Does anyone know if there is a way I can get the XCode method/class definitions (which currently sit in a drop down in outline form) list to stay permanently in a window?  I'd like to dock it somewhere in order to help me move around in my classes instead of using the drop down menu at the top of the window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key command **ctrl 2** is a pretty fast way to navigate between methods.

Just make sure your cursor is aktive in the code editor.